# Is there any way to integrate ERC20 token as payment to ecommerce

Tags: erc-20, payments

If want to integrate ERC20 token to integrate as paymen to a website. how can?

Comment: I mean you can trade ERC20 tokens for ether in a smart contract, but I think that's about the only way to do it.

Comment: You can use `web3.js` for communicating web clients with your ERC-20 smart contract.

Comment: most always answer is ERC20 token is just for exchange use not for payment.I little confuse it.So why ERC20 token create from core Eth blockchain.